# Conexión rechazada entre Servlet y Socket JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, socket

Necesito ayuda con un problema en JAVA.

Es para conectar un `Servlet JAVA` con un `Socket JAVA`.

La cosa es que localmente funciona. Ya el método creado para conectar al `Socket` desde java, se ha usado en gran cantidad de aplicaciones.

Pero yo lo estoy usando para una pagina web. Desde `JavaScript`, conecto al Servlet, este me responde todos los mensajes y demás, luego en el mismo Servlet esta el envió de datos al `Socket`, y ahí a la Base de Datos.

Todo perfecto hasta hay.

---

El problema viene, al montar mi `Servlet` en el mismo `Servidor/Hosting` donde esta el Socket, este rechaza la conexión.

Si dejo mi pagina en ese hosting junto al Socket, y dejo el Servlet en mi pc montado, perfecto. (Pero solo se puede acceder en la red local).

El problema es al montarlo al hosting publico, donde esta el Socket.

No entiendo, si sea porque al estar en el mismo hosting sea el problema.

---

Al realizar debug, el programa falla acá:

Pues haciendo debug, el se totea al llegar a la conexión con el socket.

```
socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP_D, SERVER_PORT); 
 socket.setSoTimeout(7 * 1000); 
 entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 salida = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); 
 tramaEnvio = UtilTrama.Trama_SEND(trans, ope, ced, serial, datos);
 System.out.println("Trameenvio:" + tramaEnvio);
 salida.println(tramaEnvio);
 salida.flush(); 
 tramaRespuesta = entrada.readLine();
 System.out.println("Tramarespuesta:" + tramaRespuesta);
```

Cabe recordar, que solo pasa al montarlo en el mismo hosting donde esta el Socket.

Comment: Listo gracias, acabo de modificar la pregunta, agregue la parte del código donde falla al conectar con el socket.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que aparece, cuál es el mensaje en el stacktrace? Asimismo, ¿este socket esta configurado en el mismo servidor y puerto, tienes permisos y accesos a dicho puerto?

Comment: Claro como dije en la pregunta, este se esta usando por muchas aplicaciones, pero todas montadas en otro servidor. Ya que son para uso de la red privada.
Pero mi aplicación es publica, así que el Servlet se monto en el mismo hosting y pues allí esta el problema.

Comment: Podrías agregar el stack-trace donde falla tu programa. Por otra parte si tu aplicación es web,¿ para que necesitas un socket para acceder a la BD?

Comment: @Santi92 Pues no he podido sacar el stack-trace, pues solo falla cuando esta en el hosting donde esta el Socket, y no tengo acceso.
Que porque uso Socket, porque toda la lógica esta en paquetes de oracle. Solo se puede acceder por el socket. 
Intentare montar otro server con acceso publico y probar allí. Si se soluciona tocara dejarlo. =(

Comment: @RKAZUMA entonces verifica los permisos del socket, y los parametrós que les estas enviando

Comment: ¿Puedes mirar las peticiones de red del navegador y decirnos qué te responde cuando falla?

Comment: Es esencial que obtengas el stack trace, o al menos el tipo de excepción que recibes. Agrega logging a tu aplicación para que eso quede en un archivo y puedas revisar. Para saber si es error de conexión denegada, timeout de conexión, etc.

Comment: ¿Has verificado que el puerto con valor **SERVER_PORT** esta abierto en tu maquina?, si es una maquina publica posiblemente tenga cerrado el acceso a todos los puertos excepto los normales tipo *80, 443, 22* y poco mas. Verifica que tiene conectividad al puerto SERVER_PORT

Answer (score 1):

La causa más probable es una de estas dos:

1. Estás usando la IP pública del equipo donde está el socket escuchando conexiones, y eso sólo funciona desde fuera del hosting; al estar en la misma red,o en el mismo equipo incluso, debes usar la IP interna del servidor.
2. Estás corriendo tu cliente en el mismo equipo que el servidor y estás intentando conectar a localhost (ya sea 127.0.0.1 o ::1), pero el socket sólo está unido a una interfaz de red con otra IP y no escucha en localhost.

Esa constante que tienes de SERVER_IP_D seguramente debes cambiarla cuando corres en el mismo equipo o misma red en donde está el socket escuchando.